# How do I edit a .sublime-settings file if it's inside a package?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm trying to set up a Node build system in Sublime Text. I thought I'd use [tanepiper's](https://github.com/tanepiper/SublimeText-Nodejs), and I'm following its instructions exactly, but there's a problem: my Node executable isn't found (yes, it's in my system PATH). It says to edit `Nodejs.sublime-settings` if that happens, but that file is *inside* Nodejs.sublime-package, which is an archive.

I can't edit the file in-place in the archive. I've tried extracting the archive and then zipping it up again and calling the zip a sublime-package, but that doesn't work either.

So what am I supposed to do here?

Answer (score 2):

You should create `Nodejs.sublime-settings` in your `Packages/User` folder. The settings will be merged properly. If you really feel you need to modify the packaged file, use https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer, though I'd recommend against it (for settings) as placing a file with the same name in the Packages/User folder will do what you want.